# Illegal char <:> at index 44: com.accel.ushorts.app-mergeDebugResources-70:/values/values.xml

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors

I can't build my app because of this error. I try solve this problem all day but I can't solve. Please help

**Screenshot**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjyqU.png)

Values/values.xml screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIgpR.png)

I check all xml and java files but I can't see any error.
Thanks

Comment: Do not post images of errors or code.  Copy paste them as text here.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I got error when I add this library implementation 'com.crystal:crystalrangeseekbar:1.1.3'